# C# EntityFramework include clause lost

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to get soma data from my db with a filter on child collection. I did it in this way:

```
_db.MyTable
   .Include(x => x.MyCollection.Where(y => y.MyBool == false))
      .ThenInclude(x => x.A);
```

This works fine. I get only child elements in my collection where my bool is false. Everything ok. Now I need to include another property, so I did it:

```
_db.MyTable
   .Include(x => x.MyCollection.Where(y => y.MyBool == false))
      .ThenInclude(x => x.A)
   .Include(x => x.MyCollection.Where(y => y.MyBool == false))
      .ThenInclude(x => x.B);
```

In this way I correctly include A and B, but I lose the filter! Why? How can I preserve the correct behaviour and include also B?

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using? Do you have a [mre] available (for example on github)?

Comment: @GuruStron EF Core is at version 7.0.0. Unfortunately I don't have a minimal reproducible example and I can't make it at the moment. I think this is a bug on EF Core library.

Comment: Yes, sounds like one. Try removing second filter.

Comment: @GuruStron already tried. I also tried to remove first filter but doesn't work.

Comment: @GuruStron I solved it. The solution is in the caution box at the end of paragraph at this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include. I added `.AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: Yes, that I wanted to suggest it too originally but I wondered how the first one worked.